# Compatibility Issues for SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, smo

I'm trying to execute a schema file on a SQL Server machine. I currently have both SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 installed. When I try to execute the .sql file (meant to execute on the 2008 version) I get the following error.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException: 
Failed to connect to server . --->    
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException: This SQL Server
version (10.0) is not supported
```

Is there a way to specify which version the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.dll looks at when you execute the program or some other workaround other than uninstalling the 2005 version?

**EDIT**

I'm running the .sql file from an ASP.Net application and using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO dll`

```
ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString),);
Server srv = new Server(conn);

// execute sql file
srv.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 300000;
srv.Databases[conn.DatabaseName].ExecuteNonQuery(schema);
```

Comment: What tool, utility, or application are you using to "execute the .sql file"? (SQLDMO implies to me that you're using a Command window, but that seems unlikely.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried to run SMO stuff from an ASP.NET process, but you can probably just load the file, split on "GO" and run it as a series of SQL commands without too much fuss. That should not care about the sql version issues unless there is some SQL statement that is somehow version specific.

Comment: I've thought about trying this but it seems like a hacked method and I'm concerned about comments and IF statements.

Comment: IFs -- like the IF EXISTS stuff work just fine. Or at least I've used this on lots of SSMS generated scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message you're getting, it sounds very much like you are somehow using/accessing SQL 2005 utilities. "Version 10.0" is SQL 2008 (in engineering speak, as opposed to marketing). Are you sure you're accessing the right dll?

Once upon a time long ago, I hit something perhaps similar. We had SQL 7.0 and 2000 on one box (I *said* it was long ago) and we were calling some utility via batch file, Command window, something like that, and we could only get the old/incompatible version of the utility to run. Days later, someone [Hi Greg!] thought to look a the DOS environment PATH setting, and lo and behold, because of the order the folders were listed in, the OS would find the old version before the new one. Might something like this be tripping you up now?

Comment: Ditto for verifying that you are referencing the correct SQL SMO dll. 2005 and 2008 use different SMOs which are not compatible with each other.

Comment: The strange thing about my problem is that I have the application running on a laptop with only 2008 installed and it works fine.  However, when I load it on to the server (with the same dll) it breaks.  I've tried recopying the dll over and that hasn't changed anything.